# No location on Google Maps has altitude (according to location.hasAltitude())

Tags: java, android, location, altitude

I am creating a basic *Hiker's Watch ap*p that provides the user his/her location info like (longitude, latitude, altitude, etc).

However, the altitude displayed in the logs is always `0.0` (in spite of assigning some non zero value for altitude in the Extended Controls).

According to,

```
locationProvider.supportsAltitude()
location.hasAltitude()
```

the device supports altitude but no location has any altitude.

Even Mount Everest (according to co-ordinates) "does not have" altitude.

I am getting other location details like *Latitude, Longitude*.

What can I do?

Comment: _"...in spite of assigning some non zero value for altitude in the Extended Controls"_ So, you are testing on the Android emulator? How about on a real device?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing on the emulator. I'll try it on a real device soon. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen It's working fine on my phone. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

GPS altitude can have much error rates for cheaper devices.

You can also alternatively try the SensorManager to approximate altitude using the pressure sensors which could have some inaccuracies.

```
SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE,pressure)
```

Something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private SensorManager sensorManager;
  private Sensor pressureSensor;
  private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
      float[] values = sensorEvent.values;
      flat altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE, values[0]);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    pressureSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, pressureSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
  }
}
```

Source: [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getAltitude(float,%20float))

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not really interested in using pressure sensors. Does Google Maps not provide altitude data anymore?